# Create new Index Mapping error

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, kibana

When I create an index with mapping like this one, what does it mean the _template/ word? what does the _ mean? I ask your help to understand more about creating an index, are they stored in a kind of folder, like template/packets folder?

```
PUT _template/packets
{
  "template": "packets-*",
  "mappings": {
    "pcap_file": {
      "dynamic": "false",
      "properties": {
        "timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "layers": {
          "properties": {
            "frame": {
              "properties": {
                "frame_frame_len": {
                  "type": "long"
                },
                "frame_frame_protocols": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "ip": {
              "properties": {
                "ip_ip_src": {
                  "type": "ip"
                },
                "ip_ip_dst": {
                  "type": "ip"
                }
              }
            },
            "udp": {
              "properties": {
                "udp_udp_srcport": {
                  "type": "integer"
                },
                "udp_udp_dstport": {
                  "type": "integer"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I ask this because after typing this, I recieve he following error

## ! Deprecation: Deprecated field [template] used, replaced by [index_patterns]

{
"acknowledged": true
}

I copied the pattern from this link:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/analyzing-network-packets-with-wireshark-elasticsearch-and-kibana
And I'm trying to do exactly what is taught in the link, and I already can capture files with tshark and parse copy them into a packets.json file, and I will use filebeat to transfer the data to Elasticsearch, I already uploaded some data to Elasticsearch, but it wasn't indexed correctly, I just saw a lot of information with a lot of data.

My aim is to inderstand exactly how to create a new index pattern, and also how to relate what I upload to that index.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace word `template` with `index_patterns`:

```
PUT _template/packets
{
  "index_patterns": ["packets-*"],
  "mappings": {
       ...
```

Index templates allow you to define templates that will automatically be applied when new indices are created.

After version 5.6 the format of Elasticsearch index templates has changed; the `template` field, which was used to specify one or more patterns for matching index names that would use the template at create time, was deprecated and superseded by the more appropriately named field `index_patterns` which works exactly the same way.

To solve the issue and get rid of the deprecation warnings you will have to update all your pre-6.0 index templates, changing the `template` to `index_patterns`.

You can list all your index templates by running this command:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_template/*?pretty'
```

Or replace the asterisk with the name of one specific index template.

More about ES templates is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/indices-templates.html).

Comment: Thank you Denis Rasulev. Can I ask you something else? I have filebeat, and I typed the following configuration in the filebeat.yml file: 
               setup.template.name: "packets-*"       
              setup.template.pattern: "packets-*"          
              output.elasticsearch:                                                                                     index: "packets-*"     I don't understand very well how to send my files with filebeat and match them to the _template/packets index, can you help me please Denis :) and thank you in advance for your answers and your help

Comment: In this link I asked another related question, in order to go ahead following the stepsto send data captured with tshark, through filebeat to Elasticsearch, please answer also this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50591051/send-what-i-upload-with-filebeat-to-an-index

Comment: @ManuelArmandoFloresYáñez, thanks for accepting the answer. I will check your other questions a bit later.