# Send what I upload with filebeat to an index

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, kibana, filebeat

I created an index mapping, like this one, and now I will use filebeat to send a json file to Elasticsearch, how can I make sure to configure my filebeat.yml to send the information to this new index mapping that I'm just creating?

Index mapping:

```
PUT _template/packets
{
  "index_patterns": "packets-*",
  "mappings": {
    "pcap_file": {
      "dynamic": "false",
      "properties": {
        "timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "layers": {
          "properties": {
            "frame": {
              "properties": {
                "frame_frame_len": {
                  "type": "long"
                },
                "frame_frame_protocols": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "ip": {
              "properties": {
                "ip_ip_src": {
                  "type": "ip"
                },
                "ip_ip_dst": {
                  "type": "ip"
                }
              }
            },
            "udp": {
              "properties": {
                "udp_udp_srcport": {
                  "type": "integer"
                },
                "udp_udp_dstport": {
                  "type": "integer"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

my filebeat.yml:

```
###################### Filebeat Configuration Example 
###################### #########################

# This file is an example configuration file highlighting only the most common
# options. The filebeat.reference.yml file from the same directory contains all the
# supported options with more comments. You can use it as a reference.
#
# You can find the full configuration reference here:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/index.html

# For more available modules and options, please see the filebeat.reference.yml sample
# configuration file.

#=========================== Filebeat prospectors =============================

filebeat.prospectors:

# Each - is a prospector. Most options can be set at the prospector level, so
# you can use different prospectors for various configurations.
# Below are the prospector specific configurations.

- input_type: log
  paths:
    - "/home/manuel/packets.json"
  document_type: "pcap_file"
  json.keys_under_root: true
processors:
 - drop_event:
     when:
       equals:
         index._type: "pcap_file"
enabled: false
# Change to true to enable this prospector configuration.
  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  # paths:
    #- /var/log/*.log
    #- c:\programdata\elasticsearch\logs\*

  # Exclude lines. A list of regular expressions to match. It drops the lines that are
  # matching any regular expression from the list.
  #exclude_lines: ['^DBG']

  # Include lines. A list of regular expressions to match. It exports the lines that are
  # matching any regular expression from the list.
  #include_lines: ['^ERR', '^WARN']

  # Exclude files. A list of regular expressions to match. Filebeat drops the files that
  # are matching any regular expression from the list. By default, no files are dropped.
  #exclude_files: ['.gz$']

  # Optional additional fields. These fields can be freely picked
  # to add additional information to the crawled log files for filtering
  #fields:
  #  level: debug
  #  review: 1

  ### Multiline options

  # Mutiline can be used for log messages spanning multiple lines. This is common
  # for Java Stack Traces or C-Line Continuation

  # The regexp Pattern that has to be matched. The example pattern matches all lines starting with [
  #multiline.pattern: ^\[

  # Defines if the pattern set under pattern should be negated or not. Default is false.
  #multiline.negate: false

  # Match can be set to "after" or "before". It is used to define if lines should be append to a pattern
  # that was (not) matched before or after or as long as a pattern is not matched based on negate.
  # Note: After is the equivalent to previous and before is the equivalent to to next in Logstash
  #multiline.match: after
#============================= Filebeat modules ===============================

filebeat.config.modules:
  # Glob pattern for configuration loading
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml

  # Set to true to enable config reloading
  reload.enabled: false

  # Period on which files under path should be checked for changes
  #reload.period: 10s

#==================== Elasticsearch template setting ==========================

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 3
  #index.codec: best_compression
  #_source.enabled: false
setup.template.name: "packets-*"
setup.template.pattern: "packets-*"
#================================ General =====================================

# The name of the shipper that publishes the network data. It can be used to group
# all the transactions sent by a single shipper in the web interface.
#name:

# The tags of the shipper are included in their own field with each
# transaction published.
#tags: ["service-X", "web-tier"]

# Optional fields that you can specify to add additional information to the
# output.
#fields:
#  env: staging


#============================== Dashboards =====================================
# These settings control loading the sample dashboards to the Kibana index. Loading
# the dashboards is disabled by default and can be enabled either by setting the
# options here, or by using the `-setup` CLI flag or the `setup` command.
#setup.dashboards.enabled: false

# The URL from where to download the dashboards archive. By default this URL
# has a value which is computed based on the Beat name and version. For released
# versions, this URL points to the dashboard archive on the artifacts.elastic.co
# website.
#setup.dashboards.url:

#============================== Kibana =====================================

# Starting with Beats version 6.0.0, the dashboards are loaded via the Kibana API.
# This requires a Kibana endpoint configuration.
setup.kibana:

  # Kibana Host
  # Scheme and port can be left out and will be set to the default (http and 5601)
  # In case you specify and additional path, the scheme is required: http://localhost:5601/path
  # IPv6 addresses should always be defined as: https://[2001:db8::1]:5601
  host: "https://this_is_hidden_and_changed_for_stackoverflow"

#============================= Elastic Cloud ==================================

# These settings simplify using filebeat with the Elastic Cloud (https://cloud.elastic.co/).

# The cloud.id setting overwrites the `output.elasticsearch.hosts` and
# `setup.kibana.host` options.
# You can find the `cloud.id` in the Elastic Cloud web UI.
cloud.id: "this_is_hidden_and_changed_for_stackoverflow=="

# The cloud.auth setting overwrites the `output.elasticsearch.username` and
# `output.elasticsearch.password` settings. The format is `<user>:<pass>`.
cloud.auth: "elastic:this_is_hidden_and_changed_for_stackoverflow"

#================================ Outputs =====================================

# Configure what output to use when sending the data collected by the beat.

#-------------------------- Elasticsearch output ------------------------------
output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  hosts: ["https://this_is_hidden_and_changed_for_stackoverflow"]
  index: "packets"
  template.enabled: false

  # Optional protocol and basic auth credentials.
  #protocol: "https"
  username: "elastic"
  password: "this_is_hidden_and_changed_for_stackoverflow"
#----------------------------- Logstash output --------------------------------
#output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  #hosts: ["localhost:5044"]

  # Optional SSL. By default is off.
  # List of root certificates for HTTPS server verifications
  #ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/etc/pki/root/ca.pem"]

  # Certificate for SSL client authentication
  #ssl.certificate: "/etc/pki/client/cert.pem"

  # Client Certificate Key
  #ssl.key: "/etc/pki/client/cert.key"

#================================ Logging =====================================
```

# Sets log level. The default log level is info.
    # Available log levels are: error, warning, info, debug
    #logging.level: debug

```
# At debug level, you can selectively enable logging only for some `components.`
# To enable all selectors use ["*"]. Examples of other selectors are "beat",
# "publish", "service".
#logging.selectors: ["*"]

#============================== Xpack Monitoring ===============================
# filebeat can export internal metrics to a central Elasticsearch monitoring
# cluster.  This requires xpack monitoring to be enabled in Elasticsearch.  The
# reporting is disabled by default.

# Set to true to enable the monitoring reporter.
#xpack.monitoring.enabled: false

# Uncomment to send the metrics to Elasticsearch. Most settings from the
# Elasticsearch output are accepted here as well. Any setting that is not set is
# automatically inherited from the Elasticsearch output configuration, so if you
# have the Elasticsearch output configured, you can simply uncomment the
# following line.
#xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch:
```

I want to make sure that what I will upload with filebeat, will be correctly submitted to the Elasticsearch mapping I set before, thank you very much my friends

Answer (score 0):

If you can write directly from FileBeat to ES then its a feature I'm not aware of.

I use Logstash as follows:

```
~/logs/*.log -> Filebeat --> LogStash --> ElasticSearch
```

Install FileBeat on all of your service nodes and Logstash on monitoring node(s) and let LogStash talk to ES. Its cleaner separation (Filebeat just sends raw data to a host/port) and LogStash has lots of parsing functionality (and you write transformations for the data if you like) which you'll need to populate sensible indexes in ES.

And you are using Index Template right??? (otherwise you're going to waste a lot of space in your ES cluster)

Comment: Thanks user1016765 for your answer, you asked me if I'm using an Index Template, my answer is that I don't understand very well if I do, I don't understand how to use a template, my filebeat.yml and what I PUT into Kibana is just exactly what I posted in my question, not knowing exactly what I'm doing. Altough, I was able to upload some data to Elasticsearch using Filebeat (I didn't use Logstash) and visualize it in Kibana, but for me it seemed like raw data. Can you please explain me a little about how to use a template? :) I would really appreciate it

Comment: I'm installing Logstash by the way, if you could help me with that, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: And also, what I did was to capture network data with tshark, and the result is a .json file, I really appreciate if you could help me with Logstash or another tool, thank you

Comment: According to Filebeat 6.4 docs, It's possible to send data to ES from beats (without Logstash as an intermediary), reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the template name in your `filebeat.yml` matches the name of the template you created in ES. The file you posted shows:

`setup.template.name: "packets-*"`

Notice, the value is ending with `-*`. But your template's name is `packets`, without the `-*`. Change that line to:

`setup.template.name: "packets"`